# Debugging WASM with Firefox: Imported Table with incompatible size

Tags: firefox, webassembly

I'm trying to learn web assembly. I'm able to compile wasm from C code. However I'm having a lot of difficulty trying to get my code to run in Firefox. My code is very basic:

**hello.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
</body>
<script async type="text/javascript" src="hello.js"></script>
</html>
```

**hello.js**

```
"use strict";

const imports = {
    env: {
        "abort": function() {},
        "memoryBase": 0,
        "tableBase": 0,
        "memory": new WebAssembly.Memory({ initial: 4 }),
        "table": new WebAssembly.Table({ initial: 0, element: 'anyfunc' }),
    }
}

WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(fetch('hello.wasm'), imports)
.then(obj => console.log(obj.instance.exports._add(1, 2)))
.catch(error => console.log(error));
```

**hello.c**

```
#include <emscripten.h>

EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE int add(x, y) { return x + y; }
```

I compile my code like this:

```
emcc hello.c -O1 -g4 -s WASM=1 -s SIDE_MODULE=1 -o hello.wasm --source-map-base http://localhost:8080/ --emrun
```

and I use emrun to serve my files

```
emrun --no_browser --port 8080 .
```

### The Problem

Initially, Firefox was complaining with `LinkError: "import object field 'abort' is not a Function".` Inspecting hello.wast, generated during compilation, it looks like an abort function is indeed required (I'm guessing `abort()` is an expected part of the C runtime). So, I added the `"abort": function() {},` line to the env section of `imports`.

**But now I get a `LinkError: "imported Table with incompatible size".` I'm at a loss at to what this error is trying to indicate. How can I get my wasm code to run?**

I'm trying to debug with Firefox Developer Edition 63.0b8 (64-bit).
emcc is 1.38.11.

Answer (score 2):

I am an idiot. Change the 0 here to any other number. For example:

```
"table": new WebAssembly.Table({ initial: 0, element: 'anyfunc' }),
                                          |
                                          v
"table": new WebAssembly.Table({ initial: 2, element: 'anyfunc' }),
```

This hello.js file should work.

```
"use strict";

const imports = {
    env: {
        "abort": function() {},
        "memoryBase": 0,
        "tableBase": 0,
        "memory": new WebAssembly.Memory({ initial: 4 }),
        "table": new WebAssembly.Table({ initial: 4, element: 'anyfunc' }),
    }
}

WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(fetch('hello.wasm'), imports)
.then(obj => console.log(obj.instance.exports._add(1, 2)))
.catch(error => console.log(error));
```